# Как найти все кнопки по заданному условию и у каждой вызвать функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Есть куча кнопок с `ObjectName` `radioButton_1`, `radioButton_2`...`RadioButton_48`...

Не могу понять как задать функцию сразу всем кнопкам?

```
for i in range(1, 48):
    rb = "radioButton_" + str(i)
    self.rb.setChecked(False)
```

Так не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте поиск нужных виджетов через метод `findChildren` и по условию выбирайте нужные:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        main_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()

        for i in range(10):
            name = str(i)

            button = Qt.QRadioButton(name)
            button.setObjectName('radioButton_' + name)

            main_layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)
    
    def do_all_enabled(self):
        for button in self.findChildren(Qt.QRadioButton):
            print(button.objectName())

            if button.objectName().startswith('radioButton_'):
                button.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.do_all_enabled()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```